# Why is this mapping NOT working?

Tags: key-bindings

My long term goal is to swap the <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>\</kbd> keys on my keyboard. Everything else is fine.  I am calling `vim` with

```
vim -u NONE
```

Gives me these maps:

[image]

I do

```
:map ` \
```

and get

[image]

so the mapping has definitely taken.

However, when I type, or use a mark, the keys are exactly where they would be.  I expect to be in a position where I can no longer type the ` key.

What's going on?

Comment: Based on the first line of the second window you escaped a space character in your mapping.

Comment: @BLayer - that's a sensible point and I've fixed it in the example - I still find the mapping isn't doing anything (I also feel like if I'd escaped a space, I'd expect that all my ` would get replaced by spaces? or at least removed...)

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you expect this mapping will do... For example, it will *not* replace the backquote with a backslash in Insert mode, you would need an `:inoremap` to do that. What kind of command are you trying that is unexpectedly working? Double-backquote (to go to the last position after a jump)? Also, unclear what you intend that mapping to do, since backslash is typically a dead key that does nothing... You have no other mapping, so this is just disabling it?

Comment: If you just want to swap the two keys in Normal mode (not in Insert mode), then you could use the `'langmap'` option to do that. See `:help 'langmap'` for more details and instructions. (Let me know if that's what you want, I can write an answer for it.)

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @filbranden backslash is my leader, so I use it (and `) in normal mode a lot, and I also write in latex a lot so I use both in insert mode a lot.  I would literally swap the keycaps if there were compatible.

Comment: If you want to swap them *everywhere*, then you should probably be looking into a remapping at the keyboard driver in your OS... Whatever you do in Vim, will be limited to Vim only. And Vim mappings are fairly limited for this kind of full remapping.

Comment: I'll close the question with "Needs more details", but feel free to [edit] it to explain more clearly what you're trying to accomplish or which problems you're bumping into and I'll be happy to reopen it.